# Build error: could not find `metadata` in `anchor_spl` and could not find `pda` in `mpl_token_metadata`

Tags: anchor, anchor-spl, mpl-token-metadata

In https://beta.solpg.io/tutorials, pick up the "https://beta.solpg.io/tutorials" demo project.

Here is the demo code I got: https://beta.solpg.io/65aa97e9cffcf4b13384cf03

But it failed to build.

Then I exported it to my local net env to build it.
My Cargo.toml's dependencies are:
[image]

After hours of fixing, there still error that I could not fix.

Error message are:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `anchor_spl::metadata`
 --> programs/anchor-token/src/lib.rs:4:5
  |
4 |     metadata::{create_metadata_accounts_v3, CreateMetadataAccountsV3, Metadata},
  |     ^^^^^^^^ could not find `metadata` in `anchor_spl`

error[E0432]: unresolved imports `mpl_token_metadata::pda`, `mpl_token_metadata::state`
 --> programs/anchor-token/src/lib.rs:7:26
  |
7 | use mpl_token_metadata::{pda::find_metadata_account, state::DataV2};
  |                          ^^^                         ^^^^^ could not find `state` in `mpl_token_metadata`
  |                          |
  |                          could not find `pda` in `mpl_token_metadata`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
error: could not compile `anchor-token` due to 2 previous errors
└─>
```

I know bellow import not work. And I can found replacement:  `mpl_token_metadata::types::DataV2` by google, but don't know how to import others properly.

```
use anchor_spl::{
    metadata::{create_metadata_accounts_v3, CreateMetadataAccountsV3, Metadata},
      ...
};
use mpl_token_metadata::{pda::find_metadata_account, state::DataV2};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I conquer this after days of dipping into anchor and mpl-token-metadata source code.

First, to answer a simple question to myself: playground always use latest version crate. And we can not choose which version of crate to use.

Second, `mpl_token_metadata::{pda::find_metadata_account,state::DataV2}` only exist in versions before v2.0.0(excludsive).

In latest mpl_token_metadata, there are 'mpl_token_metadata::types::DataV2', but no replacement for find_metadata_account(). So I copy find_metadata_account's code out from older version to my program.

Third, to use `anchor_spl::metadata::xx`, we must enable "metadata" feature on Cargo.toml's dependencies section. For example:
`anchor-spl = {version = "0.29.0", features = ["metadata"]}`

Finally, here is my version of 'battle-coins' example:
https://beta.solpg.io/65ace254cffcf4b13384cf14

Comment: ok, did you find out what function replaces find_metadata_account?

Comment: Not yet. Haven't got time on it.